# Use Excel 2010 macro in some (not all) xlsx workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a macro that I would like to use in some XLSX workbooks, call them **wb1.xlsx** and **wb2.xlsx**. Because they are XSLX they cannot contain any macro definitions.

My first choice to accomplish this was to use the [Personal Macro Workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx) in the XLSTART directory. However, I prefer that this not be global, that is, I do not want every workbook to access this macro, rather I would like only **wb1.xlsx** and **wb2.xlsx** to access the macro.

My next attempt was to define my macro in an Add-In, call it:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\AddIns\MyMacros.xlam

I checked the MyMacros item in the Manage Add-Ins list for **wb1.xlsx**, and then saw it was already there for **wb2.xlsx**. I then unchecked the MyMacros item in the Add-Ins list because I didn't want any future workbooks using it, but when I tried to open **wb1.xlsx** afterwards I received the error message:

> Cannot run the macro "mymacro". The macro may not be available in this
>   workbook or all  macros may be disabled.

The reason for this is because MyMacros.xlam was no longer in the Add-Ins list. Apparently any change to the Add-In list is global rather than a property of a particular workbook.

Does anyone know of any other way to access a macro from some (not all) XLSX workbooks?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the macro in an .xlsm file and then save that macro enabled file plus your wb1.xlsx and wb2.xlsx as a workspace file (*.xlw). You can then open the workspace file, which will open all three workbooks in one swoop.